# designing a COM API with a "session" object to control resource allocation

Tags: oop, com, api-design, raii

My team is designing a set of COM objects that together implement a service. Currently, the design does not include a session object. By "session object", I mean one that the client creates before using the service and deletes after using the service. I am trying to convince the team that we need such a session object in order to allow the client to control the allocation and deallocation of the service's internal resources. I'm looking for documented design patterns that help me make my case.

I know that many COM interfaces do not need such a session object. Any initialization of internal resources is done when the first object is created, regardless of what object that is, and those resources are released when the last object maintained by the server is deleted (ie, when its reference count goes to 0). Although this is perhaps simpler for the client, the problem is that the cost of the initialization must be paid at the time the first object is created. If the client is expecting that to be a lightweight operation, and most of the time it is, this initialization results in unpredictable and undesirable behavior.

By introducing a session object whose lifetime must wrap those of all other objects, the client can control when the initialization occurs and make sure that it occurs before the services managed by the session are used. (I realize that a robust design requires that my service handle multiple sessions and that the initialization price be paid on creation of the first session object and releasing of resources on deletion of the last session object.)

Is there a name for this pattern? Are there any documented examples that I can point others to in order to support my case? I realize that what I want to do is associated with RAII (Resource Allocation Is Initialization) but the motivation is a bit different.

Answer (score 1):

If you need a name for this, see the [Registry pattern](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/registry.html) (P of EAA), the [Context Object pattern](http://www.corej2eepatterns.com/ContextObject.htm) (Core J2EE Patterns) and the [Lookup pattern](http://posa3.org/ResourceAcquisition.pdf#page=3) (POSA3).

Off the top of my head, a very similar pattern is followed in COM, the [Partial Acquisition pattern](http://posa3.org/ResourceAcquisition.pdf#page=48) (POSA3), when resolving a moniker, where composed monikers keep their stuff in a context which might be useful for the next moniker.

See [`IBindCtx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms693755(v=vs.85).aspx) in the scope of [`IMoniker`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679705(v=vs.85).aspx).

A binding context object contains [binding options](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms690231(v=vs.85).aspx), [references to objects that must be kept alive](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687294(v=vs.85).aspx), [a pointer to the session's running object table](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680065(v=vs.85).aspx) and [named parameter object references](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687254(v=vs.85).aspx).  These are all used throughout 1) resolving a name to a moniker and 2) getting an actual object from a moniker.

By registering objects to the binding context, they will be kept alive for the duration of the context, which may be useful if you refer to those objects somehow, usually named objects (imagine an object that represents an actual Office document).  This is similar in effect to what you want to achieve, except that to get to the actual objects you usually need to name them or they need to be accessible from some other object that the moniker can get its hands on.

By setting object parameters, usually concrete and/or unnamed instances, they may change the way the moniker is resolved or how user interaction may happen (or not) to resolve the moniker.  In this aspect, it's not merely an optimization, although when starting with an empty binding context, it usually is used as such.

If you're the one setting the moniker's binding parameters upfront, it'll be more similar to the [Eager Acquisition pattern](http://posa3.org/ResourceAcquisition.pdf#page=35).

A major drawback of this kind of approach is that, much like just using an untyped hash table, it's hard to understand what you can put in a binding context that will actually be used by a moniker.  So in your case, I recommend you make your session object(s) have specific, typed properties whenever possible.

Note that what you're trying to achieve is also very similar to cached instance activation, as opposed to creational dependency injection.  Some dependency injection frameworks also allow that the same object be returned for some interface or some set of parameters.  If you're already using such a framework, you may avoid reinventing the wheel.